# Chrome.identity works perfectly without asking for credentials

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have implemented the chrome.identity `launchWebAuthFlow` to authenticate users of a web extension against an oauth2 provider and the entire flow works perfectly, I receive the access token back in the redirect URL, I extract the token using a regex and then it is valid and accepted to query the APIs.
However, I do not understand why it does not prompt anymore for credentials when I launch again the `launchWebAuthFlow`. Instead, it retrieves another (valid !) token in the background. Don't get me wrong, I like this, and I prefer it works in the background, but I just don't understand how. Even after clearing all cookies and local data, when I launch the `launchWebAuthFlow` again it just works in the background without asking for credentials...where are they stored?

Also, not sure if that helps, but my flow is the following:
`extension ->oauth2 server->azure ad SSO->enter credentials->redirect to extension`
So the real authentication is managed by Azure AD. However, even when I'm signed out from Microsoft, the extension keeps getting a valid auth token when the below code is triggered and without asking for credentials...so the credentials must be stored somewhere...

```
chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow(
    {
        url: dev.identity_url(),
        interactive: true
    },
    function (responseWithToken) {
        // the access token needs to be extracted from the response.
        console.log(responseWithToken);

        let token = responseWithToken.match(/(?<=access_token=).*(?=&token_type)/);
        token = token[0];

        chrome.storage.local.set({ "auth-token": token }, function () {
            console.log(`Access Token has been saved: ${token}`);
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: It doesn't ask for a token anymore because after the token has been retrieved the first time, it gets cached into the browser till it expires. You can remove the cache at chrome://identity-internals by revoking it. Then after that it will ask for another authentication

Comment: Hi, thanks, this is the problem. Even after reinitializing chrome, in chrome://identity-internals there is only the token for Chrome Media Router
which I suppose is connected to my gmail account (I signed-in). But ther eis no trace of any other token, howver the chrome.identity launchWebAuthFlow works exactly as described above (login prompt only the first time, then it auto reloads a valid token in background without any issues)...I am wondering what is going on :D

Comment: @Doc-Han any idea why the credentials are not stored in chrome://identity-internals? It has to be stored somewhere if chrome does not ask for credentials anymore and gets a valid token in the background anyway, right?